# Remote Desktop Services (2008) allows everyone in

Tags: domain, remote-desktop-services, windows-terminal-services

My RDS 2008 Terminal Server (domain-joined) allows anyone to login remotely. I am trying to restrict that down to one Security Group: DOMAIN\TerminalServerUsers.

I've been testing with a new user who is only a member of Domain Users.

The Remote tab under Terminal Server shows Domain\Domain Admins and DOMAIN\TerminalServerUsers.

Local Security Policy Allow Logon Through RDS shows Domain\Domain Admins and DOMAIN\TerminalServerUsers.

Local Security Policy Allow Local Login shows Domain\Domain Admins and DOMAIN\TerminalServerUsers.

Local Security Policy Deny Logon Through RDS is blank

Group Policies do not show alterations to policies relating to RDS.

Where else might I restrict Terminal Server users down to a group?

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using the `Remote Desktop Users` local group on the server? You can modify it with a group policy.

One way to add users/groups to `Remote Desktop Users` manually is (explained in details [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc743161(v=ws.11).aspx)):

1. Start the System tool. To start the System tool, click Start, click
   Run, type control system and then click OK.
2. Under Tasks, click Remote settings.
3. In the System Properties dialog box, on the Remote tab, click Select
   Users. Add the users or groups that need to connect to the RD
   Session Host server by using Remote Desktop. The users and groups
   that you add are added to the Remote Desktop Users group.

Test if it works and then you may set it with a group policy with SOM only the servers you need to restrict access to. A pretty neat guide is available [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17671.how-to-add-domain-usersgroup-to-remote-desktop-users-group-on-servers-using-group-policy.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the problem. Of course, this is a server I inherited with little information as to how it got into this configuration.

Under the Local Security Policy, "Administrators" was inside Allow Logon Through Remote Desktop Services. The Administrators group on the Terminal Server had Domain Users inside of it. I removed that and scoped it down to Domain Admins and the Terminal Server group I created.

Comment: That's pretty bad. Time to audit all the other inherited systems I think.